# actionscript: can I get the http request URL?

Tags: http, actionscript

a.swf is loaded in a.html which is hosted at http://www.a.com/a.html.

I want to know, if user browses http://www.a.com/a.html, in actionscript, can I get the http request URL? In this example I want http://www.a.com/a.html.

Answer (score -1):

Flash: `this.loaderInfo.url`

Flex: `Application.url` or `Application.loaderInfo.url`